# "Create" route path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I find the resource route method quite convenient, but I totally hate that it does not create `create` and `destroy` path helpers.

I understand that writing

```
<% form_for(@object) %>
```

is supposed to automatically get the route name, and that we can play with arrays or symbols to automatically get the namespace/prefixes when they exist, but I have many routes with complicated `scope` definitions, and not being able to get `create_xxx` helpers totally annoys me

Is there no simpler solution than to write ? (I am trying to keep the default RESTful URLs while generating the helpers)

```
complicated_scope do
  resources :my_resources, except: [:create, :destroy] do
    post '', on: :collection, action: :create, as: 'create' # plus this generates a pluralized version, not very intuitive `create_complicated_scope_my_resourceS_path`
    delete '', on: :member, action: :destroy, as: 'destroy'
  end
end
```

EDIT. My example of 'somewhat complicated scope'

```
# Company access routes under /company/
namespace :company do
  # I need a company id for all nested controllers (this is NOT a resource strictly speaking, and using resources :companies, only: [] with 'on: :collection' doesn't generate appropriate urls)
  scope ':company_id' do
    # Company administrators
    namespace :admin do
      # There is a lot of stuff they can do, not just administration
      namespace :administration do
        # There are several parameters grouped in different controllers
        resources :some_administrations do
          ... # finally RESTful actions and others here
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you give more examples of what kind of complicated scope your working with? I'd think the complicated scope is probably a smell and it's worth investigating if you can simplify your routing rather than work around it by looking for a `create_xxx` helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resourceful routing does create `create` and `destroy` helpers, but they're implied by the type of HTTP request being made (POST and DELETE respectively) so the routing helper methods should work fine with the code you've provided.

Suppose you have the following route definition:

```
complicated_scope do
  resources :my_resources
  end
end
```

As a simple example, in the case of delete, you could use a named route like so:

```
link_to "Delete [resource]", complicated_scope_resource_path(id: @my_resource.id), method: :delete
```

Since the HTTP verb disambiguates the controller action this helper method routes to the destroy method of the controller.

Alternatively, you should be able to use the array syntax as well.

```
link_to "Delete [resource]",  [:complicated_scope, @my_resource], method: :delete
```

The same goes for forms:

```
<%= form_for [:complicated_scope, @my_resource] do |f| %>
```

If `@my_resource` is a new object (not persisted), as in the case of a `new` action this would be equivalent to sending a `post` request to /complicated_scope/my_resource with the form params going in the body of the request.

Alternatively if `@my_resource` exists, as in the case of an `edit` action, the above would be equivalent to sending a `PUT/PATCH` which will route to the `update` action of your controller with `/complicated_scope/my_resource/:id/update`.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand the argument of the route automatically changing to the the `patch` method when the object exists. Often I am using special forms for the create action (such as modals), and I have a totally different piece of code for the update action, so I forget the resource helper is for the "rails way" with a `_form` object shared between create and update...

Comment: Yeah, I think that's typical. Forms for updating an object are usually different than for creation (in my experience at least). However, the above should still apply in that circumstance and you can be explicit in specifying `method: :post` or `method: :patch` in the form as need be.